How can I wire four Peltier modules in parallel with current limiting?
I am currently working on a project to cool different materials for a local young student program with engineering.
My thinking was to attach Peltier modules to different materials and, using an IR camera, see the spread of temperature change on a monitor so kids can see the effects of conduction versus insulation amongst materials.
The issue we have is deciding how to power all four Peltier modules in parallel where each is rated 12V 6A.
Finding a power supply with great enough amperage supply is one option but I want to ask if anyone could think of another way to get our required amperage down. If even possible, I am not an electrician or electrical engineer so I'm going off my instinct and background knowledge so please be patient.

If you want kids to see the effects of conduction versus insulation amongst materials, then heating with resistors is waaaaay more controllable, intuitive, likely to be successful, than cooling with Peltiers, what with Peltiers needing a BIG hot-side heatsink, and you not appearing to understand them at all (from your question). You can buy aluminium power resistors if you want to be able to bolt them to things, eg https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/chassis-mount-resistors/0157572. You can get different values for different power output with a fixed voltage, which you appear to have decided upon.

Thanks for your reply, Neil. We could choose to go for heating instead like you suggested, we were just choosing cooling as our option for this demo, I will bounce the idea around with my colleague to see what he thinks is a good option. Our voltage can vary, I was just going off the Peltier modules I found online rated for 12V 6A, that's why the limit was set there.

Also Neil, would the flat plate of the chassis-mount resistor you shared with me be the place where the heat is supplied? We need to mount each resistor/TEC(if we choose Peltier) on a flat plate of material, between metal and other mediums. Thanks.

The entire surface of the resistor body gets hot. However, it has a flat side so that it can be mechanically mounted to a flat plate for heatsinking purposes.

The thing is you don't actually need to power them at the full current capacity. If you have a bench top power supply that can provide a few amps, you can just turn the voltage down (but a bench top power supply will be self-limiting anyway). You will still get a substantial temperature differential with a reduced voltage.
Or, you could sequence them separately. Just power them one at a time for each material.
Or, if you don't need cooling, you can use chassis-mount resistors and tailor the value to your existing power supply (if you have one already). See Ohm's Law for details on sizing resistors. The downside is you will get no cooling effect. May not be needed for a temperature gradient demonstration cause cooling would simply be the inverse of heating anyway. The plus side is you don't have to deal with heatsinking (the TEC will burnout if they are not heatsinked properly).

Thanks MOSFET for your reply. I like the idea of sequencing them separately, one idea we had was to get 4 individual 12V 6A power supply units and plug them in to a surge protector then have that be the on/off switch, so I like this thinking. Dependent on budget and materials we may go with a 30A power supply up to 450 W, or the four individual power supply bricks instead. If we choose to try and power them under a power supply rated for 8A or less, could we wire them in parallel to each other, and have the current split amongst them? Would that just give us less effective/efficient cooling?

If you supply 12 V, each Peltier module WILL try to draw 6 amps, for a total of 24 amps.  The 8 amp power supply will either shut down or burn up.  To reduce the current in a Peltier module you have to reduce the voltage.

@callen12 yes, they will draw equal current if they are powered by the same voltage. The exact performance comes from the curves in the datasheet. For what you are trying to do, the specific thermal performance won't matter.
